# Drawing routes using Gmaps.js

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm making a small demo app for myself and I use Gmaps.js library as a main tool to work with map and have a problem when I try to draw a route.

This code (from documentation) works excellent

```
 map.drawRoute({
                    origin: [-12.044012922866312, -77.02470665341184],
                    destination: [-12.090814532191756, -77.02271108990476],
                    travelMode: 'driving',
                    strokeColor: '#131540',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                    strokeWeight: 6
                });
```

this one (mine) doesn't work

```
 map.drawRoute({
                    origin: [32.090814532191756, -85.090814532191756],
                    destination: [32.000814532191756, -85.090814532191756],
                    travelMode: 'driving',
                    strokeColor: '#131540',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                    strokeWeight: 6
                });
```

Can you help me to find out the difference? 
I will be thankful for advice about any other libraries to work with map.

Comment: [The posted code works for me (fiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ygpxsr5v/1/)  Perhaps you have your map centered in the wrong place?

Comment: @geocodezip seems that is everything ok with map position, because I have made map markers for this points and I see it at once.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (the posted code works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ygpxsr5v/1/))

Comment: @geocodezip yeah, I see. I copied your code and it doesn't work in my file.

Comment: Not sure what you expect us to do.  If you provide a [mcve] that exhibits the real issue, then someone might be able to help.  Another option would be to compare your code with the working example to see what the difference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was in the Google Maps API key.